# Recursive functions - argument value not updating after some value

Tags: recursion

I have written one recursive function and pointer to integer is passed as an argument. That integer value is incremented in function, but I am facing a strange issue that after some value its value never get updated. Even I am checking the value at that address.

Below is the code:--

```
   computeWait(long long int begin, long long int begin2, long long int w,
    int* current, int limit)      
   {    
      long long int next = 0, arrival = 0;

      long long int next1 = 0, service = 0;

      long long int serviceTime = 0;

      long long int wait = 0;

      static long long int Ta = 0;

      static long long int Ts = 0;
      static long long int W = 0;

      while(*current < limit)
      {
         next = (16807 * begin) % m;
         arrival = -200 * log((double)next/m);

         next1 = (16807 * begin2) % m;
         service = -100 * log(EDRN((double)next1));

         wait = max(0, (w + service - arrival));
         Ta = Ta + arrival; 
         Ts = Ts + service; 
         W = W + wait;

         *current = *current + 1;;
         computeWait(next, next1, wait, current, limit);
       }   

       printf("\n\nTotal arrival %Ld Total service %Ld Total wait %Ld\n", Ta/limit, Ts/limit, W/limit);
   }

   int main(int agrc, char* argv[])    
   {

       int num = 0;
       int currentValue = 0;        // seed number
       int end = 1000000;

       computeWait(1, 46831694, 0, &currentValue, end);          
   }
```

After 103917, its value doesnot get updated and it gives memory protection failure.

Please let me know where I am doing something wrong as it seems so trivial to fix it.

Thanks,
Neha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I did not really try to understand the code, but I saw some big numbers and the word recursion.
So I would guess its a stack overflow because your recursion is too deep?